# UseEffect triggering without respect to dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function below which i used as an array dependency to a `useEffect` handler

```
const handleInputUpdate = (event) => {
    const eventValue = event.target.value;
    setState({ ...state, answer_text: eventValue, trigger: true })
    // console.log("I am changing for no reason")
  }
```

Below is the `useEffect` handler

```
  useEffect(() => console.log(" I am changing for no reason in useeffect"), [handleInputUpdate])
```

What i want is the `useEffect` handler to run only when the `handleInputUpdate` function is called but it runs also on component mount.

**Here's what i've observed**

1. The `handleInputUpdate` function doesn't run on component mount but only i need it to
2. Without respect to the above observation, the `useEffect` handler runs anyway.

**Here's what i've tried**

1. I tried consoling a text inside the `handleInputUpdate` function to see whether it runs on component render but it doesn't.

Even though the function doesn't run, the `useEffect` handler triggers anyway which is not what i want.

How can i solve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useEffect` dependency array is not used to trigger the effect when a function is called; the elements of the array are observed for any change and then trigger the effect.

In this case, `handleInputUpdate` will change on every render because it is not [memoised](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), so the effect will also run on every render.

Since `handleInputUpdate` changes the state when it is called, you are better off adding that state to your `useEffect` dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (answer_text && trigger) {
    console.log("I am changing for a reason in useeffect")
  }
}, [answer_text, trigger])
```

Comment: with the logic given to me by both parties, i was able to resolve my problem.
Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

The `handleInputUpdate` function, while it doesn't *run* on render, looks like it's *created* when the component runs, just before rendering. Since it won't be `===` to the value last in the dependency array - the `handleInputUpdate` from the prior render - the effect callback will run.

You need to observe changes to the `answer_text` value in state instead.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // ...
}, [state.answer_text]);
```

I would also recommend separating out your state into different variables - these aren't class components, don't feel like you have to mash everything together into a single object structure.

```
const [text, setText] = useState('');
```